# How to make child 100% of screen

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this layout:

```
 <ul class="all-content white-bg">
    <row>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <!-- Content -->
            <div class=" content white-bg fullscreen clearfix">
                <h3 class="cardTitle text-center">How-to: NAVBAR</h3>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <iframe src="/nav_bar.htm">
                        </iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <figure>
                            <figcaption></figcaption>
                            <pre>
                                <code>
                                </code>
                            </pre>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card" id="1">
                <div class="card-front">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">NAVBAR</h5>
                        <p class="card-text"></p>
                        <button type="button"><a href="#">Go</a></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card" id="2">
                <div class="card-front">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">JUMBOTRON</h5>
                        <p class="card-text"></p>
                        <button type="button"><a href="#">Go</a></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have 24 cards. I want to click the card for each and reveal the div with class content white-bg full screen.
I tried a few things and nothing seems to work. I making basically making 24 of those content divs but im only doing one right now for testing. I've googled and tried other solutions like cobinations of position absolute and relatives, tried displaying as a table, tried min-width 100%, tried 100% of the viewport,tried moving the div somewhere else but nothing seems to work

Comment: Maybe `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh` is what you're looking for?

Comment: tried that already :/

Comment: Share you some css

Answer (score 0):

Try it, I believe this should work:

```
.content.fullscreen {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css try:

```
div.fullscreen {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

That should make the div fill the screen, regardless of position. Any div with the class fullscreen will take that unless there is other css you are using that is being considered to be more important.